# Sendmail with TLS support changes FROM: address

Tags: sendmail, tls

I have multiple domains on one server and when sending email to
server, which supports TLS, server changes FROM field to default
domain ($j).
What should i do (in .mc level please) to remain primary domain (all
domains are qualified)?

```
Jul 14 10:59:16 server sendmail[19537]: p6E7xGt3019537: from=user@domain-a.com, size=491, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<1310630356.19535@domain-a.com>, relay=loggedinuser@localhost
Jul 14 10:59:17 server sendmail[19538]: STARTTLS=server, relay=localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1], version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=NOT, cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits=256/256
Jul 14 10:59:17 server sendmail[19537]: STARTTLS=client, relay=[127.0.0.1], version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits=256/256
Jul 14 10:59:17 server sendmail[19538]: p6E7xG06019538: from=<user@domain-b.com>, size=607, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<1310630356.19535@domain-a.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA,relay=localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]
Jul 14 10:59:18 server sendmail[19537]: p6E7xGt3019537: to=recepient@domain-c.com, ctladdr=user@domain-a.com (1005/100), delay=00:00:02, xdelay=00:00:02, mailer=relay, pri=30491, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (p6E7xG06019538 Message accepted for delivery)
Jul 14 10:59:18 server sendmail[19540]: STARTTLS=client, relay=smtp3.domain-c.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits=256/256
Jul 14 10:59:18 server sendmail[19540]: p6E7xG06019538: to=<recepient@domain-c.com>, ctladdr=<user@domain-b.com> (1005/100), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120607, relay=smtp3.domain-c.com. [93.40.95.67], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (Ok: queued as 2117414003)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you need to do. Let's say you want to 
have the name mx.domain-a.com for the MTA.
Then you need to add `Cw localhost  mx.domain-a.com` to sendmail.mc or use 
`FEATURE` `use_cw_file`.
To relay your domains add them to 'relay-domains' file.
To have a specific user to have a specific domain add them
to `genericstable` :

> tsst tsst@domain-b.com

see also [Generics Table](http://www.madboa.com/geek/sendmail-genericstable/) and [Features](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/features.html).